# How do I fix this compile error for my eye writer project

Tags: xcode, macos, sdk

I am trying to recreate the EyeWriter 2.0 project from instructables.I have downloaded everything needed but when compiling comes I got this error.I downloaded that version of sdk on that specific place and i still got the same error.

error: unable to find sdk '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk' (in target 'RemoteEyeTracker')

Can someone explain to me what means in target RemoteEyeTracker?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you Xcode cannot find the Mac 10.5 SDK in Xcode's app bundle. I doubt recent versions of Xcode have good support for the 10.5 SDK since it shipped with Xcode 3, whose first release was in 2007. You will probably have to build your project with a newer version of the Mac SDK. Updating a project that was built for Mac OS X 10.5 to recent versions of macOS is going to be a lot of work.